# Passing * in as command line argument in simple Java Calculator

Tags: java

So,
the question is basic. In the code below, when I pass command line argument as `java CommandLineDemo 3 5 *` the file names in my current directory are being listed. Doing some research in Google I found out we should supply `*` as `'*'` in command line.

My question is, how can my code be modified so that it accepts `'*'` in command line and performs product of `operand1` and `operand2`

```
class CommandLineDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int operand1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int operand2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        char theOperator = args[2].charAt(0);
        System.out.print(args[0] + args[2] + args[1] + " = ");
        switch(theOperator) {
            case ('+'):
                System.out.println(operand1 + operand2); break;
            case ('-'):
                System.out.println(operand1 - operand2); break;
            case ('*'):
                System.out.println(operand1 * operand2); break;
            case ('/'):
                System.out.println(operand1 / operand2); break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Operator selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using "*" instead.  The quotes are removed automatically

Comment: use x instead of * :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the command line argument as a single string (Example: "2 3 +") with the below modified code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class CommandLineDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String strArray = Arrays.toString(args);
        strArray = strArray.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replaceAll("[, ]", "");
        String[] splits = strArray.split("");

        int operand1 = Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
        int operand2 = Integer.parseInt(splits[2]);
        char theOperator = splits[3].charAt(0);

        System.out.print(splits[1] + " " + splits[3] + " " + splits[2] + " = ");

        switch(theOperator) {
            case ('+'):
                System.out.println(operand1 + operand2); break;
            case ('-'):
                System.out.println(operand1 - operand2); break;
            case ('*'):
                System.out.println(operand1 * operand2); break;
            case ('/'):
                System.out.println(operand1 / operand2); break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Operator selected");
        }
    }
}
```

**The usage & output looks like this:**

```
C:\Users\sarath_sivan\Desktop>java CommandLineDemo "2 3 +"
2 + 3 = 5

C:\Users\sarath_sivan\Desktop>java CommandLineDemo "2 3 -"
2 - 3 = -1

C:\Users\sarath_sivan\Desktop>java CommandLineDemo "2 3 *"
2 * 3 = 6

C:\Users\sarath_sivan\Desktop>java CommandLineDemo "2 3 /"
2 / 3 = 0

C:\Users\sarath_sivan\Desktop>java CommandLineDemo "2 3 a"
2 a 3 = Invalid Operator selected

C:\Users\sarath_sivan\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a meta character in the shell, which means it has special meaning. So you need to escape it with the `\` No need to modify the code , instead just type `\*` to mean `*`

Comment: @Snacky Srikanth isn't my solution not working out?

Comment: codeMan changed the answer ;) they were suggesting passing `5\*3` but the argument list clear states it wants `5 3 \*`. So I guess I can remove my first comment ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you share your e-mail with me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend you program. Passing `*` as `'*'` is because shell (or more precisely, Linux shell, have little knowledge about windows cmd :p) will perform [file name expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), if you pass `*` directly, it will be expanded as all the files in your current directory. `'*'` prevent this and pass `*` to your program as command line argument.

Comment: but, when my code is compiled, passing `'*'` returns default case in switch

Comment: @Snacky It works on my box. I use `java CommandLineDemo 3 5 '*'`. My shell is bash 4.1.2 . BTW, what's your environment? Linux or windows cmd?

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea You're assuming the OP is using a Linux shell

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yep, only have a Linux machine at hand :p.